# Insert Template with Loop x Amount of Times

Tags: vba, excel, loops, do-loops

I'm back with another question that probably has a simple answer. I really fall down when it comes to loops, so this is what I am trying to build.

I am building a form where user will type in a number between 1 and 156 (named range "GenNo") and click a Generate button.

I need a loop that will copy a template built in the "Template" tab of the spreadsheet with the named range also being "Template", and then **insert** it into the main form page the specified amount of times. This way the rest of the content and other named ranges should be pushed down accordingly.

Probably a very simple answer but I am terrible when it comes to loops and would not know where to start.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: This attempt only generates one template in the form:

```
Sub Generate()
    ' Check if payslips are already generated
    If Sheets("Data").Range("GenLogic").Value = 1 Then
    MsgBox ("Already Generated! Please clear the form and regenerate.")
    Else
    Sheets("Data").Range("GenLogic").Value = 1
    End If
    ' Loop code
        Do Until Sheets("Data").Range("LoopLogic").Value = Range("GenNo").Value
        Sheets("Template").Range("Template").Copy
        Sheets("Overpayment Form").Range("Start").Insert
        Range("LoopLogic") = Cell.Value + 1
        Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: I have edited my original post with my attempt. Thanks.

Comment: Worth noting: you inform the user he needs to clear the form and regenerate, but you have no check to ensure this is done before continuing.  You may want to add an `exit sub` statement after the first if clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would give this a shot; note that i removed your updating of your loop variables. Also, i've rewritten your loop to use a for, and shift down on insert.

```
Sub Generate()
' Check if payslips are already generated
If Sheets("Data").Range("GenLogic").Value = 1 Then
MsgBox ("Already Generated! Please clear the form and regenerate.")
Else
Sheets("Data").Range("GenLogic").Value = 1
End If
' Loop code
Dim iFrom As Long, iTo As Long, i As Long
iFrom = Sheets("Data").Range("LoopLogic").Value
iTo = Range("GenNo").Value
For i = iFrom To iTo
    Sheets("Template").Range("Template").Copy
    Sheets("Overpayment Form").Range("Start").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Next


End Sub
```